# SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>)

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql-9.1, postgis, plpython

I have python 2.7 and I have weather script which returns temperature infos, I would like to implement this script into PostgreSQL. I always got this error: `DETAIL:  SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 10)`

code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetWeather(lon float, lat float)
    RETURNS float
    AS $$
    import urllib2
    import simplejson as json

    data = urllib2.urlopen(
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/station?lat=%s&lon=%s&cnt=1"% (lat, lon))
    js_data = json.load(data)
    if js_data['cod'] == '200': 
    if int(js_data['cnt'])>0: 
    station = js_data['list'][0] 
    print 'Data from weather station %s' %station['name']
    if 'main' in station: 
    if 'temp' in station['main']: 
    temperature = station['main']['temp'] - 273.15 
    else:temperature = None
    else:temperature = None

    return temperature

    $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

I tried this version too, but its not working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetWeather(lon float, lat float)
    RETURNS float
    AS $$
    import urllib2
    import simplejson as json

    def get_temp(lat, lon):
    data = urllib2.urlopen(
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/station?lat=%s&lon=%s&cnt=1"% (lat, lon))
    js_data = json.load(data)
    try:
    return js_data['list'][0]['main']['temp']
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return None

    $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Comment: Are those first 3 lines supposed to be part of the Python? And that last line? Because that's not Python.

Comment: Also the rest of it, if it *is* Python, is wrongly indented.

Comment: it is sql with python. whats wrong with the code?

Comment: please make break and indent after every `:` as it should be done in Python. There is a good chance that you see what was wrong with your code, it may even be enough to make it working.

Comment: @m.wasowski I made breaks.. but its  still not working

Comment: please edit your question then...

Comment: I edited but I cant execute this code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have `plpython3u`, but it should also work for Python 2.7 using `plpythonu` (just change that part of the following and nothing else).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetWeather(lon float, lat float)
  RETURNS float AS $$
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
else:  # Python 3
    from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

def get_temp(lon, lat):
    data = urlopen(
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/station?lat=%s&lon=%s&cnt=1"
        % (lat, lon))
    js_data = json.loads(data.read().decode('utf-8'))
    try:
        return js_data['list'][0]['main']['temp']
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return None

return get_temp(lon, lat)
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

Note that the above is with a [4-space indent convention (PEP 8)](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). If you are new to Python, I'd recommend going through a few tutorials to understand the syntax and use of indents.

Answer (score 0):

You got your data structure wrong (yeah, indentation matters...)
Anyway, here is solution for you:

```
def get_temp(lat, lon):
    data = urllib2.urlopen(
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/station?lat=%s&lon=%s&cnt=1"% (lat, lon))
    js_data = json.load(data)
    try:
        return js_data['list'][0]['main']['temp']
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return None
```

Output:

```
In [121]: get_temp(50,50)
Out[121]: 275.15
```

Comment: `DETAIL:  IndentationError: expected an indented block (<string>, line 10)`

Comment: check in pure python, it works fine - and returns correct results. I have no experience with embedding scripts in postgresql, so I won't be guessing why you get this error. I would recommend reading postgresql documentation on the topic.